# Bubble sort: average number of total key comparisons

Tags: algorithms

I want to know the steps for finding a Formula for *Average number of total comparisons in bubble sort*.
Please look at this example:

> ```
> 4 3 2 1 -> 3 2 1 4 ->   3 comparisons
> 3 2 1 4 -> 2 1 3 4 ->   2 comparisons
> 2 1 3 4 -> 1 2 3 4 ->   1 comparisons
> ```

For ordered and reverse ordered input we have different formula for number of total comparisons:

```
Min = n-1
Max = n(n-1)/2
```

*And I want a formula with steps to get average of it* - all possible inputs - / expected number of key comparisons for each of *n* input values selected from a uniformly random source

**My try**

```
(Sum of total comparisons)/(n-1) =>  n(n-1)/2/(n-1) => (n-1)
```

*NOTE : (n-1) is number of steps*

is it right?

[image: LOOK AT THIS I wrote everything]

Comment: (I see a `buble`, more important: what is `bubble descending sorting/mode`? `average` of/over *what*?)

Comment: @greybeard In this example the array is totaly descending i mean all of the numbers should be sorted  4 3 2 1 . so when we have this array we have different formula for sum of Comparisons and we have min max and average in this form but if we do'nt have descending array like : 3 1 2 4 we have different formula for Comparison we have just N( N-1 )/2  and no min or ave or max form

Comment: So we have  2 forms of buble sort : 1- it isn't totaly Ordered or Disordered like 2 3  1 4  and 2- totaly ord or disord like : 1 2 3 4 and 4 3  2 1

Comment: An average with respect to which input distribution?

Comment: @Steven YES exactly

Comment: If you fix the input permutation then using the word *average* is misleading. You're simply interested in the number of comparisons that bubble search performs on this particular input.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you but i don't undrestand . you mean if i change the input then we don't need any average ? actually i  read Neoplitan's book for designing algorithms, and according to that book, we could calculate the average for the second type of bubble algorithm that I explained, and I searched and found that N(N-1)/4  but  i was just looking for a way to prove it  and explain more .

Comment: Can you help me please to find the right answer ? i don't know what's the problem . did i explain bad , unclear ? this is the question that is valid and my teacher asked me to find the average  for this type of bubble sorting . i searched and i found but i want more explian to undrestand how did we get this formula ? n(n-1)/4

Comment: As Yuval said, if you are looking at a fixed instance then there is nothing to average. Your algorithm performs some number of comparisons that is completely determined by the instance. Yet, you keep asking for an average without telling us what you want to average over... Do you want to know the average number of comparisons involving an element when the input is a sequence sorted in reverse order? I.e., the answer to the following question: given an  input element $x$ selected uniformly at random, what the expected number of comparisons involving $x$?

Comment: @Steven Thank you i undrestand now sorry i try to explian  . i just read neapolitan's book and like any algorithm i just want to find a formula for ave that showes me The order of the algorithm (T(n) O x^2 ) . yeah i want  the average number of comparisons but not in a sequence sorted in reverse order . it was just a example . i want the ave for a sequence like this  2 3 1 4  i mean not reverse just a normal sequence  and yes : ( given an input element x selected uniformly at random, what the expected number of comparisons involving x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that all elements in the array you're sorting are distinct.

The average number of comparisons over all permutations of the array is equal to the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of the number of comparisons, so let's calculate that instead.

The total number of comparisons done to sort some array $A$ (length $N$) is equal to $N - 1 + (\text{Number of inversions in } A)$, where an inversion is a pair of indices $i < j$ where $A_i > A_j$. By linearity of expectation, the expected number of comparisons is thus
$$
N - 1 + \sum_{i < j}P(A_i > A_j) = N - 1 + \frac{N(N - 1)}{4}
$$

Comment: What, as per question, are the steps for finding such?

Comment: @Andi Qu thank you so much